# Using ToolkitScriptManager in Masterpage asp.net without form tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I am trying to use the below code referenced from ,
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Session-Timeout-message-before-Session-expires-in-ASPNet.aspx

I want to implement this code in a master page. But I am thrown with an error that toolkitscriptmanager must be placed inside a form tag since form tag cannot be added here I need alternative solution for this issue.

Kindly suggest an idea .

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CS.aspx.cs" Inherits="CS" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        .modalBackground
        {
            background-color: Black;
            filter: alpha(opacity=60);
            opacity: 0.6;
        }
        .modalPopup
        {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            width: 300px;
            border: 3px solid #0DA9D0;
            border-radius: 12px;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .modalPopup .header
        {
            background-color: #2FBDF1;
            height: 30px;
            color: White;
            line-height: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-top-left-radius: 6px;
            border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        }
        .modalPopup .body
        {
            padding: 10px;
            min-height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .modalPopup .footer
        {
            padding: 6px;
        }
        .modalPopup .yes, .modalPopup .no
        {
            height: 23px;
            color: White;
            line-height: 23px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        .modalPopup .yes
        {
            background-color: #2FBDF1;
            border: 1px solid #0DA9D0;
        }
        .modalPopup .no
        {
            background-color: #9F9F9F;
            border: 1px solid #5C5C5C;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <h3>
        Session Idle:&nbsp;<span id="secondsIdle"></span>&nbsp;seconds.</h3>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake" runat="server" />
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeTimeout" BehaviorID="mpeTimeout" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopup"
        TargetControlID="lnkFake" OkControlID="btnYes" CancelControlID="btnNo" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
        OnOkScript="ResetSession()">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
        <div class="header">
            Session Expiring!
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            Your Session will expire in&nbsp;<span id="seconds"></span>&nbsp;seconds.<br />
            Do you want to reset?
        </div>
        <div class="footer" align="right">
            <asp:Button ID="btnYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" CssClass="yes" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnNo" runat="server" Text="No" CssClass="no" />
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SessionExpireAlert(timeout) {
            var seconds = timeout / 1000;
            document.getElementsByName("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
            document.getElementsByName("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
            setInterval(function () {
                seconds--;
                document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
                document.getElementById("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                //Show Popup before 20 seconds of timeout.
                $find("mpeTimeout").show();
            }, timeout - 20 * 1000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location = "Expired.aspx";
            }, timeout);
        };
        function ResetSession() {
            //Redirect to refresh Session.
            window.location = window.location.href;
        }
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards,
Arun